# замена строк в текстовом файле

Tags: python, replace

Как удалить все скобочки в файле? Код читаю вроде все верно но не работает

```
def clear_strings(self):
        with open('Val.h', "r") as f:
            new_f = f.readlines()
            with open('Val.h', "r+") as new_new_F:
                for line in new_f:
                    for new_line in new_new_F:
                        if '),' in line:
                            print('replacing')
                            new_line.replace('),','')
```

Comment: У вас в условии `replace` написано `),`, оно является верным для вашей задачи? И что нужно делать с такой `(` скобкой?

Comment: Вообще задача стоит избавится от некоторых элементов в частности скобки

Comment: Как насчёт использования регулярных выражений? Читаете строку из файла, пропускаете через регулярку, записываете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать регулярные выражение при помощи импорта `re` и функции [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
import re
with open('file1.txt') as g:
    new = g.read()
    v = re.sub('[()]', "", new)
    print(new, '\n', v)
with open('file1.txt', 'w') as b:
    b.write(v)
```

---

вывод

```
(Уже сентябрь.)  
Осень )тихонько вступает( в свои права. )
Дерев(ья, кусты, трава – )все меняет свое зеленое одеяние,( 
переодеваясь в пестрые наряды.) 

Уже сентябрь.  
Осень тихонько вступает в свои права. 
Деревья, кусты, трава – все меняет свое зеленое одеяние, 
переодеваясь в пестрые наряды.
```

Comment: виноват с релярным выражениями не часто сталкиваюсь а как еще туда добавить двойные запятые и одиночные [ или

Comment: @ЕВГЕНИЙГ `re.sub('[()[;"]', "", new)`

Comment: а они как то комбинируются между собой?потому что у меня посути 4 задачи

Comment: @ЕВГЕНИЙГ как понять комбинируются

Comment: то есть хотел бы удалить к примеру ,, и {[ и ]}

Comment: @ЕВГЕНИЙГ `re.sub('[()\[\]{}"]', "", new)`

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде нет записи значения после замены. Т.е. замена производится, но никуда не записывается. Простенький пример кода с перезаписью в переменную:

```
def clear_strings(self):
    with open('Val.h', "r") as f:
        q = ''
        new_f = f.readlines()
        for line in new_f:
            q += line.replace('),','')
    print q
```

в переменной q будет храниться уже замененный текст